# Can the school see my computer?

Tags: windows, wifi, surveillance

During all this covid-19 stuff my school is letting students sign out computers and take them home until the end of the school year. When you log in to the computers, you log in to your school gmail account.

So even though I’m connected to my own wifi network can they still view my screen at all times? I know they can read my emails but if I were to go on Omegle or something like that, would they know?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can the school see what you are doing on their laptop when connected to your home WiFi?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/149004/can-the-school-see-what-you-are-doing-on-their-laptop-when-connected-to-your-hom)

Comment: As the duplicate will talk about, it largely depends on whether the laptop has tracking or monitoring software installed. And it likely will. As a side note, it's never a good idea to do personal stuff on "someone else'e computer" and assume any privacy, whether it's a school computer, a work computer, or a friend's computer.